# In Geometry Nodes, how to Loop Cut (or Subdivide along one axis only)?

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes, geometry

Is it possible to do the equivalent of a Loop Cut in Geometry Nodes?  I don't see a Loop Cut node, nor a way to subdivide a mesh along a single axis.

Ultimately what I'm trying to do is this: I have a cube that I want to cut grooves in around the x-axis, spaced evenly apart across the length (y) of the object.  My plan is to make more edges and then convert them to curves, so I can sweep geometry along the curves to cut ridges into my shape.

Is this possible with geonodes?

(EDIT: Changed "rectangle" to "cube" - sorry for the confusion)

Comment: The thing is, it sounds a bit like this might not be the final result you want to achieve. Is this only going to be done on a simple rectangle? If so then it is quite trivial: Take a _Grid_, set the size as you need it, set _Vertices Y_ = 2 and _Vertices X_ = n+2 if you want n cuts. But if you just say rectangle as example or placeholder for something more complex which you are aiming for, then this might be more complicated. And maybe if you explain more with screenshots or sketches how you want to use the curves and sweep geometry, maybe other totally different solutions might be better.

Comment: Hey @GordonBrinkmann, yes I am actually just trying to figure out how to make a loop cut the same way you would in edit mode, so a rectangle works as an example.  But what do you mean by starting with a grid?

Comment: In _Geometry Nodes_ just _Add_ > _Mesh_ > _Primitive_ > _Grid_. That is a rectangle where you can set the subdivisions separate in both directions. But as I suspected your question seems to be more a typical [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)... if you don't want a simple rectangle in the end but a general way to do loop cuts, what I explained will not help you at all.

Comment: This is very good point @GordonBrinkmann, and you are correct, I'm definitely asking an XY problem.  It's mostly because I'm building a brainstorm design project, not an actual design where I have a specific problem, but a brainstorm design where I can iterate a lot of different ideas quickly and see what sticks.  So understanding how to loop cut in geonodes would help me profoundly, though now that I've spent more time with this I'm realizing it isn't possible.

Comment: Also, @GordonBrinkmann I apologize for the confusion, when I said 'rectangle' above I meant 'cube.'  So I was confused when you mentioned the grid because I'm imagining a 3D object.